# CXF - Webservice method with parameter type as Element

Tags: web-services, generics, cxf

I am trying to develop SOAP based webservice using CXF. My requirement is to accept any XML data structure as method parameter and then the logic to parse/handle this data would be internally taken care by webservice (A generic webservice for accepting request).
Hence I want to declare the method parameter as either org.w3c.dom.Element or org.w3c.dom.Document. I tried declaring method with these types but it gave an error.

Can anyone please let me know how, I can achieve this? I dont want to use REST approach.

Answer (score 0):

Would a Provider based service work?  Alternatively, make the method param a DOMSource or just Source.   That may work better.

Comment: What is provider based service work? Can you please explain in detail.
Meanwhile I will try with DOMSource.